# Get only data that are 30 days old using jq

Tags: json, date, select, jq

i have a json file with user access data similar to this. I am trying to filter out user (name and accessDate fields) who has not accessed system for last 30 days. Does anyone know if this can be done using jq operation?

```
"items": [
{
    "id": "1",
    "accessDate": "2019-11-13T11:35:39.1097956",
    "user":{
        "name": "john doe"
    }
}
{
    "id": "2",
    "accessDate": "2019-10-13T11:35:39.1097956",
    "user":{
        "name": "scott doe"
    }
}
{
    "id": "3",
    "accessDate": "2019-9-13T11:35:39.1097956",
    "user":{
        "name": "matt doe"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the input is valid JSON, with "items" as the top-level key, then the value of "items" can be updated relative to `now` as follows:

```
(now - 30*24*60*60 | strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")) as $recent
| .items |= map( select((.accessDate
                         | sub("-(?<d>[0-9]-)";"-0\(.d)")) >= $recent) )
```

(The invocation of `sub` is needed to handle months given as `-d-`.)